# Plaid API not functioning: Claims I'm missing my client_id and secret

Tags: plaid

I am trying to run the Plaid API Quickstart. I have tried following these steps (https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/) in Python, and these steps (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGBvKDGgPjc) in Node. The video steps in Node are working much better for me, although I know nothing about Node.

When the server is launched (please excuse me if I'm using incorrect jargon, I've spent the last 6 months learning Python and mostly have no idea what I'm talking about), I get this:

[image].

As you can see, it says `client_id`, `secret` are missing fields.

However, in the file, they are clearly present (of course I've replaced them with x's). The code in the ".env" file is pasted below:

```
# Get your Plaid API keys from the dashboard: https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
PLAID_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Use 'sandbox' to test with fake credentials in Plaid's Sandbox environment
# Use 'development' to test with real credentials while developing
# Use 'production' to go live with real users
PLAID_ENV=sandbox

# PLAID_PRODUCTS is a comma-separated list of products to use when
# initializing Link, e.g. PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions.
# see https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/#link-token-create-request-products for a complete list.
# Only institutions that support ALL listed products will be displayed in Link.
# If you don't see the institution you want in Link, remove any products you aren't using.
# Important:
# When moving to Production, make sure to update this list with only the products
# you plan to use. Otherwise, you may be billed for unneeded products.
# NOTE:
# - 'income_verification' has to be used separately from all other products due to the specific flow.
# - 'payment_initiation' has to be used separately from all other products due to the specific flow.
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions,identity

# PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES is a comma-separated list of countries to use when
# initializing Link, e.g. PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA.
# Institutions from all listed countries will be shown. If Link is launched with multiple country codes,
# only products that you are enabled for in all countries will be used by Link.
# See https://plaid.com/docs/api/tokens/#link-token-create-request-country-codes for a complete list
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA

# Only required for OAuth:
# For sandbox, set PLAID_REDIRECT_URI to 'http://localhost:3000/'
# The OAuth redirect flow requires an endpoint on the developer's website
# that the bank website should redirect to. You will need to configure
# this redirect URI for your client ID through the Plaid developer dashboard
# at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api.
# For development or production, you will need to use an https:// url
# Instructions to create a self-signed certificate for localhost can be found at https://github.com/plaid/quickstart/blob/master/README.md#testing-oauth
# If you are not set up to use localhost with https:// on your system, you will be unable to test OAuth in development or production.
# In this case you can leave the PLAID_REDIRECT_URI blank.
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000/
```

Would someone please explain?

I've tried re-adding these keys and making sure they're in all of the files that they need to be.

Comment: As a troubleshooting suggestion, can you try hard-coding these values into the actual code, rather than the .env file? (i.e., replace mentions of os.getenv('PLAID_CLIENT_ID') in the actual .py file with your client ID, and so forth). If that works, that would narrow down the issue to being .env file (is it named .env rather than .env.example? is it in the right location?) or with the dotenv dependency.

Comment: did you end up managing to fix the issue?

Comment: @Mr.O I have not fixed the issue. Im trying to get this done in Replit. I tried to go around the issue by posting a bounty for someone to implement for me, but they said it couldn’t be done within Replit at this time. He did say, however, he got it running on his machine in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @JackHanel and you're using the correct Client ID and secret for the corresponding environment, sorry if i'm being obvious

Comment: @Mr.O yes…I don’t understand why it’s not working

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today with Plaid.  My simple error was I added my client_id and secret into the .env.example file and not the .env file.  Once I put in the right place I got the Launch Link button and was on my way.